# Tabular layout with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a table like layout in flexbox and it's not working.

**I want something like this:**

```
< image > | < image > 

Text      | Text
```

**Instead I get:**

```
< image > Text | < image > Text
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#item {
  flex-direction: row;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="item"><img src="img/3dsteak.png" />Steak</div>
  <div id="item"><img src="img/burger.png" />Burger</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `flex-direction` property applies only to flex containers. In your code it's on the flex items. This is having no effect. Try this:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="item">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100">
        <span>Steak</span>
    </div>
    <div id="item">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100">
        <span>Burger</span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

(Maybe I shouldn't have used kitten placeholders considering your text, but I'm sticking with this simple and convenient tool. No offense to cat lovers intended.)

Answer (score 0):

Is simple as you mentioned. You should have the text separately in a div. And do some more magic with flex in `#item`. Refer the code below

```css
body {
  margin:0
}
#main_background {
  background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
#container {
  /*width: 100%;
  height: 100%;*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#item {
  -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari */
  flex-flow:  row wrap;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 200%  ;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right:10px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;

}
img {
  width:100%;
  margin-right:10px;
  height:150px
}
img:last-child {
  margin-right:0
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="item"> 
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/668243842185973760/n15no_UF.jpg"/>
    <div>
      Steak
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="item"> 
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/668243842185973760/n15no_UF.jpg"/>
    <div>
      Steak
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. Are you expecting this?

```css
#main_background {
  background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
#container {
  /*width: 100%;
  height: 100%;*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#item {
  margin:10px;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari */
  flex-direction:  row;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 200%  ;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="item"> <img src="img/3dsteak.png"/><br /> Steak </div>
  <div id="item"> <img src="img/burger.png"/><br /> Burger </div>
</div>
```